# How do I import a .csv file with a column of coordinates for polygons to a geodataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

I've got a csv file that includes a column with the coordinates for a series of polygons.

For instance:

```
  patch_ID  geometry                                                 flow   hab_area    Total   Portion of Flow     flow_area   Dispersal   mean_flow
1   156     POLYGON ((369000.0000019073 548000.0000019073,...   1.620000e-12    3874.00     3.740000e-11    4.328570    4.180000e-16    d4  3.081707
3   65      POLYGON ((362000.0000019073 560000.0000019073,...   1.010000e-12    404.25      3.740000e-11    2.709681    2.510000e-15    d4  1.447226
4   170     POLYGON ((383000.0000019073 520000.0000019073,...   8.770000e-13    5397.25     3.740000e-11    2.342323    1.620000e-16    d4  3.270493
6   179     POLYGON ((390000.0000019073 484000.0000019073,...   7.350000e-13    12341.50    3.740000e-11    1.963216    5.960000e-17    d4  3.796241
10  162     POLYGON ((385000.0000019073 541000.0000019073,...   3.530000e-13    1546.75     3.740000e-11    0.943354    2.280000e-16    d4  1.139087
```

I have imported it as a pandas dataframe with pd.read_csv(), how do I now convert it to a geodataframe with Geopandas such that the Geometry column is the geometry of the polygons? When I try:

```
df1 = gdp.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = 'geometry')
```

I get an error: Input geometry column must contain valid geometry objects.

Then when I try to check the validility of the geometry with some code I found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267801/csv-to-geodataframe-how-to-have-valid-geometry-objects)

```
for index, row in blbog_unpro.iterrows():
geom = row['geometry']
if len(geom.coords) <= 2:
      print("This row has an invalid polygon geometry")
```

I get another error: 'str' object has no attribute 'coords'

I'm stumped.

Comment: You need to use the *Well Known Text* (WKT) format.  See if anything on this page helps: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html

Comment: Yes! That has sorted it, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  You might want to post the answer (and mark it as the accepted answer) so that others can learn from what you have found out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by DatHydroGuy the trick was to use Well Know Text(WKT) format. The following code sorted the problem:

```
from shapely import wkt
df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = 'geometry')
```

Thank you DatHydroGuy